# Minecraft fabric with IntelliJ, failed to verify authentication

Tags: minecraft-fabric

I have been experiencing issues where I can still launch the game, but cannot log in to any servers with the Minecraft Fabric. The first time I ran minecraft fabric on intellij I wasn't logged in to my Minecraft account - (I didn't hit the check box for 'Stay logged in'). Was this possibly the cause of this issue? Here is the error that it says in the console:

```
[10:47:22] [Render thread/ERROR] (Minecraft) Failed to verify authentication
 com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsException: Status: 401
    at com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientHttpException.toAuthenticationException(MinecraftClientHttpException.java:56) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:112) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.<init>(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:42) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.createSocialInteractionsService(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:151) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.createSocialInteractionsService(MinecraftClient.java:683) [minecraft-1.17.1-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.17.1+build.46-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.<init>(MinecraftClient.java:496) [minecraft-1.17.1-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.17.1+build.46-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:153) [minecraft-1.17.1-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.17.1+build.46-v2.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[?:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.game.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:234) [fabric-loader-0.11.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:153) [fabric-loader-0.11.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:28) [fabric-loader-0.11.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]
Caused by: com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientHttpException: Status: 401
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.readInputStream(MinecraftClient.java:77) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.get(MinecraftClient.java:47) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:104) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    ... 13 more
```

I am new to creating mods so I may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete this error from showing up. If you want to join a server on your minecraft account, use Auth me for fabric (https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/auth-me). Drop it in your /mods folder in IntelliJ project.