# Minecraft fabric using Intellij, cannot authenticate

Tags: authentication, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-fabric, microsoft-account

I am developing a mod for Minecraft Fabric 1.16.5 and I need to log into servers.  However, I cannot authenticate and log into my account.  My account has been migrated, meaning it is a Microsoft account.
**What I've tried:**

- Using the AuthMe mod to authenticate (https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/auth-me) as suggested here ([Minecraft fabric with IntelliJ, failed to verify authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957585/minecraft-fabric-with-intellij-failed-to-verify-authentication)).  This doesn't work as the 1.16.5 version doesn't support Microsoft logins.  I also cannot find any other mods that would server this purpose.
- Using `--username email123@hotmail.com --password Password1` (as well as `--username=email123@hotmail.com --password=Password`, this variation had the same result) (those aren't my actual credentials).  This didn't work and had the same result as if I hadn't put those arguments there in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method (AuthMe) was fixed in version 2.0.0: https://github.com/axieum/authme/releases

To authenticate, install the mod and place it inside the `mods` directory of the run instance.  Next, in the multiplayer screen, click the authenticate button at the top left, select Microsoft, and log in.

This will allow you to connect to servers from inside a development environment.