# "Execution failed for task ':runClient'" Fabric 1.17.1

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

when I run my mod it freezes when it gets to the `"Caused by: com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientHttpException: Status: 401"` error, I expect the error since I am not signed into a Minecraft Account but the freezing was odd. Once I stopped the process Eclipse gave me this error.

```
 Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
 Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-16.0.2.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I tried running with the other options, no effect. I removed the code and .json files I added right before seeing this issue for the first time, nothing. Even a simple restart did nothing. Here are some system specs and the log.

Windows 11 Home 21H2,
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz,
16.0 GB RAM

```
 [07:48:50] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/GameProvider) Loading Minecraft 1.17.1 with Fabric Loader 0.12.12
[07:48:50] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader) Loading 52 mods:
    - fabric 0.45.2+1.17
    - fabric-api-base 0.4.0+cf39a74318
    - fabric-api-lookup-api-v1 1.5.0+e821752d18
    - fabric-biome-api-v1 3.2.2+cf39a74318
    - fabric-blockrenderlayer-v1 1.1.6+cf39a74318
    - fabric-command-api-v1 1.1.4+cf39a74318
    - fabric-commands-v0 0.2.3+cf39a74318
    - fabric-containers-v0 0.1.13+cf39a74318
    - fabric-content-registries-v0 0.4.1+3447790d18
    - fabric-crash-report-info-v1 0.1.6+cf39a74318
    - fabric-data-generation-api-v1 1.1.1+6f83e76518
    - fabric-dimensions-v1 2.0.15+b556f28c18
    - fabric-entity-events-v1 1.4.1+377137cc18
    - fabric-events-interaction-v0 0.4.12+e99fbe1218
    - fabric-events-lifecycle-v0 0.2.4+cf39a74318
    - fabric-game-rule-api-v1 1.0.8+cf39a74318
    - fabric-gametest-api-v1 1.0.5+234bdc2e18
    - fabric-item-api-v1 1.3.0+6617390918
    - fabric-item-groups-v0 0.3.2+cf39a74318
    - fabric-key-binding-api-v1 1.0.6+2a2bb57318
    - fabric-keybindings-v0 0.2.4+cf39a74318
    - fabric-lifecycle-events-v1 1.4.6+0392f3a618
    - fabric-loot-tables-v1 1.0.5+cf39a74318
    - fabric-mining-level-api-v1 1.0.3+cf39a74318
    - fabric-mining-levels-v0 0.1.7+cf39a74318
    - fabric-models-v0 0.3.1+cf39a74318
    - fabric-networking-api-v1 1.0.14+cf39a74318
    - fabric-networking-blockentity-v0 0.2.12+cf39a74318
    - fabric-networking-v0 0.3.3+cf39a74318
    - fabric-object-builder-api-v1 1.11.1+f907116918
    - fabric-object-builders-v0 0.7.8+cf39a74318
    - fabric-particles-v1 0.2.5+cf39a74318
    - fabric-registry-sync-v0 0.8.0+ea29b33318
    - fabric-renderer-api-v1 0.4.5+cf39a74318
    - fabric-renderer-indigo 0.4.9+cf39a74318
    - fabric-renderer-registries-v1 3.2.6+cf39a74318
    - fabric-rendering-data-attachment-v1 0.1.6+cf39a74318
    - fabric-rendering-fluids-v1 0.2.1+cf39a74318
    - fabric-rendering-v0 1.1.7+cf39a74318
    - fabric-rendering-v1 1.10.1+377137cc18
    - fabric-resource-loader-v0 0.4.10+f09604ce18
    - fabric-screen-api-v1 1.0.5+cf39a74318
    - fabric-screen-handler-api-v1 1.1.9+cf39a74318
    - fabric-structure-api-v1 1.1.15+cf39a74318
    - fabric-tag-extensions-v0 1.2.3+cf39a74318
    - fabric-textures-v0 1.0.7+cf39a74318
    - fabric-tool-attribute-api-v1 1.3.3+3b96517518
    - fabric-transfer-api-v1 1.5.4+cf39a74318
    - fabricloader 0.12.12
    - java 16
    - minecraft 1.17.1
    - mythicislands 1.0-1.17.1
[07:48:50] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Mixin) SpongePowered MIXIN Subsystem Version=0.8.4 Source=file:/C:/Users/creep/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.fabricmc/sponge-mixin/0.10.7+mixin.0.8.4/7a4ca9d54d9ae564dea0363d668036a8420ed9b8/sponge-mixin-0.10.7+mixin.0.8.4.jar Service=Knot/Fabric Env=CLIENT
[07:48:51] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Mixin) Loaded Fabric development mappings for mixin remapper!
[07:48:51] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Mixin) Compatibility level set to JAVA_16
[07:48:52] [main/WARN] (FileUtil) Configuration conflict: there is more than one oshi.properties file on the classpath
[07:48:52] [main/WARN] (FileUtil) Configuration conflict: there is more than one oshi.architecture.properties file on the classpath
[07:48:57] [Render thread/INFO] (Minecraft) Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[07:48:57] [Render thread/ERROR] (Minecraft) Failed to verify authentication
com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsException: Status: 401
    at com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientHttpException.toAuthenticationException(MinecraftClientHttpException.java:56) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:112) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.<init>(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:42) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.createSocialInteractionsService(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:151) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.createSocialInteractionsService(MinecraftClient.java:670) [minecraft-project-@-mapped.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.<init>(MinecraftClient.java:429) [minecraft-project-@-mapped.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:179) [minecraft-project-@-mapped.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[?:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:608) [fabric-loader-0.12.12.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:77) [fabric-loader-0.12.12.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23) [fabric-loader-0.12.12.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]
Caused by: com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientHttpException: Status: 401
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.readInputStream(MinecraftClient.java:77) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.get(MinecraftClient.java:47) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:104) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    ... 13 more
[07:48:57] [Render thread/INFO] (Minecraft) Setting user: Player592
[07:48:57] [Render thread/WARN] (FabricLoader/Mixin) @Inject(@At("INVOKE")) Shift.BY=3 on fabric-lifecycle-events-v1.mixins.json:client.WorldChunkMixin::handler$zbf000$onLoadBlockEntity exceeds the maximum allowed value: 0. Increase the value of maxShiftBy to suppress this warning.
[07:48:57] [Render thread/INFO] (Minecraft) [STDOUT]: Registering Mod Items for mythicislands
[07:48:57] [Render thread/INFO] (Minecraft) [STDOUT]: Registering ModBlocks for mythicislands
[07:48:57] [Render thread/INFO] (Minecraft) [STDOUT]: Hello Fabric world!
[07:48:57] [Render thread/INFO] (Indigo) [Indigo] Registering Indigo renderer!
[07:48:58] [Render thread/INFO] (Minecraft) Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.2 build 10
```

If there is any way to fix this it would be greatly appreciated, I looked over the internet and while some solutions came up, none worked. This happened out of nowhere after adding some code but as stated removing said code does nothing.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169704/10952503) can help you